# Why is my Swift app not connecting to my Database?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, xcode, swift

Here is the code that I am executing when the user presses the "Register" button on a register page. I just want the script to send the info to my Register.php page then put the email and password into the database.

```
@IBAction func RegisterButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = EmailTextField.text
    let userPassword = PasswordTextField.text
    let userRepeatPassword = RepeatPasswordTextField.text

    // Check for empty fields
    if(userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userRepeatPassword.isEmpty) {

        // Display alert message

        displayAlertMessage("All fields are required.")

        return;
    }

    // Check if passwords match
    if(userPassword != userRepeatPassword) {
        // Display an alert message
        userPassword == ""
        displayAlertMessage("Passwords do not match.")
        return;
    }

    // Send user data to server side
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "www.testsite.com/Register.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            println("result: \(resultValue)")

            var isUserRegistered:Bool = false
            if (resultValue=="Success") {
                isUserRegistered = true
            }

            var messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
            if (!isUserRegistered) {
                messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String!
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                //Display alert message with confirmation
                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }

                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Register.php

```
<?php
require(“Connect.php”);
require(“SQLData.php”);
$email = htmlentities($_POST[“email”]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST[“password”]);

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password)) {
    $returnValue[“status”] = “error”;
    $returnValue[“message”] = “Missing required field”;
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$dao = new SQLData();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails)) {
    $returnValue[“status”] = “error”;
    $returnValue[“message”] = “User already exists”;
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password);

if($result) {
    $returnValue[“status”] = “Success”;
    $returnValue[“message”] = “User is registered”;
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>'
```

Comment: What is your question? And trivial: If you are really concerned about the passwords of your users. You are doing some things really (REALLY) wrong.

Comment: Can you see where I am going wrong? It is not populating the database, is there anyway to test if its being sent to the php pages?

Comment: So your question is: Why is my Swift app not connecting to my Database? Please edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you entered the variable name in mysql incorrectly vs the php db file. They are case sensitive. Check to make sure the the column names in mysql "user" table php script and no spaces. Hope that helps